# Kafka Direct Stream to DataFrame not working with window

Tags: scala, apache-spark, spark-streaming, rdd

I have the given piece of code. I'm running this on Spark 2.3.1 using Zeppelin 0.8.0 and org.apache.spark:spark-streaming-kafka-0-10_2.11:2.3.1.

```
stream.window(Minutes(5),Seconds(20)).foreachRDD { rdd =>
    val lines = rdd.map(record => record.value())
    val words = lines.flatMap(line => line.split(" "))
    val pairs = words.map(word => (word, 1))
    val wordCounts = pairs.reduceByKey((x: Int, y: Int) => (x + y))
    wordCounts.toDF("word", "count").createOrReplaceTempView("words")
}
```

However when I try to query the words table inside the sliding window, I am presented with the following error:

```
org.apache.spark.SparkException: Job aborted due to stage failure: Task 0.0 in stage 540.0 (TID 3036) had a not serializable result: org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.ConsumerRecord
Serialization stack:
    - object not serializable (class: org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.ConsumerRecord, value: ConsumerRecord(topic = test, partition = 0, offset = 249, CreateTime = 1547626717449, checksum = 3583250337, serialized key size = -1, serialized value size = 4, key = null, value = test))
```

Any suggestions on how to get this working? Seems like a very basic example.

If I run it without the window function, it works properly.

Answer (score 0):

Apparently you need to transform the stream in the transform(...) to a stream without ConsumerRecord. Then you can call window on the cleaned stream. You can then transform that stream and build the resulting table.

```
val cleanedStream = kafkaStream.transform(rdd => rdd.map(record => record.value))

val windowedStream = cleanedStream.window(Minutes(5),Seconds(20))

val transformedStream = windowedStream.transform(rdd => {
    val words = rdd.flatMap(line => line.split(" "))
    val pairs = words.map(word => (word, 1))
    pairs.reduceByKey((x: Int, y: Int) => (x + y))
})

transformedStream.foreachRDD { rdd =>
    rdd.toDF("word", "count").createOrReplaceTempView("words")
}
```